# golang: can i share C.int between packages

Tags: go, cgo

in the main package i have:

```
var foo C.int
foo = 3
t := fastergo.Ctuner_new()
fastergo.Ctuner_register_parameter(t, &foo, 0, 100, 1)
```

in the fastergo package i have:

```
func Ctuner_register_parameter(tuner unsafe.Pointer, parameter *C.int, from C.int, to C.int, step C.int) C.int {
    ...
}
```

if i try to run it, i get:

```
demo.go:14[/tmp/go-build742221968/command-line-arguments/_obj/demo.cgo1.go:21]: cannot use &foo (type *_Ctype_int) as type *fastergo._Ctype_int in function argument
```

i am not really sure what go is trying to tell me here, but somehow i think it wants to tell me, that all C.int are not equal? why is this the case? how can i solve this / work around?

Comment: The two types somehow seem to be different (_Ctype_int and fastergo._Ctype_int). I'm not sure exactly how cgo works but where does C.int comes from? Is it from some imported package?

Comment: @Laurent "C" is a pseudopackage to use C code in go. Read: http://golang.org/doc/articles/c_go_cgo.html basically I am referring to the exact same type (a C-language integer) twice and Go does not see them as equivalent.

Comment: Try defining `_Ctype_int` in the `fastergo` package, then consistently referring to it as `fastergo._Ctype_int`. They are currently in different scopes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `_Ctype_int` doesn't begin with a Unicode upper case letter, the type is local to the package. Use Go types, except in the C wrapper package where you convert them to C types. The wrapper package should hide all the implementation details.

You don't provide sufficient information for us to create sample code which compiles and runs. Here's a rough outline of what I expected to see:

```
package main

import "tuner"

func main() {
    var foo int
    foo = 3
    t := tuner.New()
    t.RegisterParameter(&foo, 0, 100, 1)
}
```

.

```
package tuner

import (
    "unsafe"
)

/*
#include "ctuner.h"
*/
import "C"

type Tuner struct {
    ctuner uintptr
}

func New() *Tuner {
    var t Tuner
    t.ctuner = uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(C.ctuner_new()))
    return &t
}

func (t *Tuner) RegisterParameter(parameter *int, from, to, step int) error {
    var rv C.int
    rv = C.ctuner_register_parameter(
        (*C.ctuner)(unsafe.Pointer(t.ctuner)),
        (*C.int)(unsafe.Pointer(parameter)),
        C.int(from),
        C.int(to),
        C.int(step),
    )
    if rv != 0 {
        // handle error
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your great feedback, but allow me to check: `C` transforms C types into package-local Go types (indicated by the leading `_`) and those are inherently incompatible with types from other packages -- even for basic types like `C.int`. The solution is to convert to Go types as soon as possible and use Go types (that are compatible over package boundaries) everywhere else. This requires to write a somewhat clean wrapper. If I wanted quick&dirty I could copy&paste everything from `tuner` to `main` (spaghetti style) and things would work as well...

Comment: forgot to mention your name, @peterSO

Comment: @peterSO: Since `ctuner uintptr` is lowercase (eg. not exported),  what is the reason not to declare it as `ctuner *C.ctuner`?

Answer (score 0):

As explained by peterSO, you can't pass `C.int` between packages. However, you can pass pointers between packages by converting the pointer type. To do this, you would define a named type in the target package, import that type into the calling package and covert via `unsafe.Pointer`. There isn't any point in doing this with a single int.

However, it is helpful if you keep code to convert complex types in a package; for example an array of strings (or any sort of nested array).

The example below is for exporting a go function to be called in C, but this works in reverse, ie. if you want to call a C functions which a returns nested array.

```golang
package convert

import "C"

type PP_char **C.char
func From_c_to_go(arr_str PP_char, length int) []string {
    // Some operation on the Ctype
    var slice []string
    for _, s := range unsafe.Slice(arr_str, length) {
        if s == nil {
            break
        }
        x := C.GoString(s)
        slice = append(slice, x)
    }
    return slice
}
```

```
package main

import "C"
import "convert"

//export myFunc
func myFunc(arr_str **C.char, length int){
    retyped_arr_str := convert.PP_char(unsafe.Pointer(arr_str))
    slice := convert.From_c_to_go(retyped_arr_str, length)
    // Do something with slice
}
```

You could instead decide to pass instance of `unsafe.Pointer` as an argument to the go function in the target package and perform the type conversion in that function.